# Apply the same string format to a varying number of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Is there a way to apply the same format to a list of multiple real variables without a necessity of making a list? There are a lot of tutorials, but every one of them omits this problem.
Say, I have reals:

```
variable = 123.234
another = 1.54816
var = 99.9994
```

Comparing to Fortran, I want to get (`'_'` representing a whitespace):

```
write(*,'(3f8.3)') variable, another, var
```

output:

```plain
_123.234___1.548__99.999
```

or something like this in Python:

```
print("{:8.3f}".format(variable, another, var))
```

preserving the same output as for Fortran.

I know I can make a list of variables and then use a for loop, but I'd rather avoid that since it introduces unnecessary lines in the code.

Comment: So you want the output as: `output: 123.234   1.548  99.999`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the varying nature of the original code (to an extent), you can use the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), and pass as many variables as you need, without needing to change the string itself:

```
print(''.join(f"{num:8.3f}" for num in (variable, another, var)))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```py
var1, var2, var3 = 123.234, 1.54816, 99.9994
# print('output: {:7.3f}   {:7.3f}  {:7.3f}'.format(var1, var2, var3))
print('output:' + (' {:7.3f} '*3).format(var1, var2, var3))
```

You will get:

```bash
output: 123.234     1.548   99.999
```